# Get record using JComboBox from database and get another record to textfield following combobox record?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, jcombobox

Can I know how we can get record using JComboBox from database and at the same time get another record from database to JTextField following what we choose in combobox?Both records are in database.
Example:Get **employees name** from database using combo box, make selection using the combo box, then get **employee id** in text field...
Thank you.

I'm trying to make a Java frame program having a text area, a combo box link to database which is stock items name and a text field for fill in stock items id. User either use combo box choose items name show items id in text field or fill in items id to show the item name in the combo box automatically.

How do I do that actually?

```
try {
     // Load the driver
     Class.forName(
             "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
     System.out.println("Database connected.");
     s = cn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs1=s.executeQuery("select StockName from StockDetail");
      while (rs1.next()){ 
        itemCombo.addItem(rs1.getString("StockName"));
    }
      /*String sl;
     sl = "select StockID from StockDetail where StockName='" + stockno.getText();
      ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery(sl);
      while(rs2.next()){
      stockno.setText(rs2.getString("StockID"));
      }*/
      rs1.close();
      s.close();
      cn.close();
 } catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Strange set of tags. You mention JComboBox and set c# tag. I would say it's java and swing tags. How your problem is related to sql?

Comment: Ops,Sorry.Thanks for info...

Comment: I don't know what to answer. How to do that? Well doing it. There is no trick or rule, the fact that you are using JComboBox and JTextField is tangencial. Just make your UI, ask for the fields in the database, display them, select one, and then fire a database query with the field selected and put the result in the JTextField. Yes there is some work to do, but the answer is "just do it". Go one step at a time starting with hardcoded queries until everything works out. Your question needs to be more specific, what is holding you back?

Comment: I was try few different ways code,but I'm fail get result that I prefer.